# Changing attribute on click event (too fast)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an **each** function that determines when a link is clicked within an ID. Once the click has happened, it takes the relevant attributes and associates them to the main image.

This functionality can also include a **video**, so if the html contains an id called `#video` it takes the video attribute and sticks it in the predefined `<video>`.

I currently have other functions that are not in the below pen like `destroyZoom()` (which destroys the zoom functionality which is specifically for the .main-image).

**Problem:** When users are switching between the images  (especially video), the zoom layer automatically activates on top of the image. (i have placed placeholders for the functions).

Can someone recommend an elegant way of handling this situation or how i have written this functionality.

**Please note:** number 5 image is video.

**EDIT: UPDATED THE CODEPEN AND CODE BELOW TO CONTAIN THE ZOOM FUNCTIONS**

```js
$('#product-gallery-super').children().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var prodImg = $(this).attr('data-image');
  var imgSrc = $(this).children().attr('src')
  var vidCheck = false;
  var mainImg = $('.main-image');

  if (imgSrc != 'http://yi.yoga/images/cs.jpg') {

    $(this).addClass("active-thumbnail").siblings().removeClass("active-thumbnail");

    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'video') {
      $('.main-image').hide();

      if (!$('.product-video').hasClass('product-video')) {

        var videoLink = $(this).attr('href');
        var videoImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

        var video = '<div class="video-container"> <video class="flat-video product-video" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="mainVideo" poster="' + videoImg + '" autoplay autobuffer width="100%" height="auto"> <source src="' + videoLink + '"> <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf" width="100%" height="auto"> <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false"> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"> <param name="flashvars" value="file=' + videoLink + '"> <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf"><![endif]--> <img src="' + videoImg + '" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Video"></object> </video>  <span class="playPause icon-play off"></span> <div class="controls-bar off"> <div class="duration"> <div class="duration-amount"></div> </div> </div> <div class="top-controls-bar off"> <div class="info"> </div> </div> </div>';

        $('.container').prepend(video);

        // START VIDEO FUNCTION videoInitate();

      }

    } else {
      mainDestroy()

      $('.video-container').remove();

      $('.main-image').show();
      $('.main-image').attr('src', prodImg);

      $('.product-zoom').elevateZoom({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        zoomType: "window",
        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: 750,
        responsive: true,
        borderSize: 1,
        borderColour: '#DDDDDD',
        lensBorder: 1,
        lensSize: 200,
        scrollZoom: false,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: 1,
      });

    }

  }

});

function mainDestroy() {
  $('.zoomContainer').remove();
  $('.product-zoom').removeData('elevateZoom');
  $('.product-zoom').removeData('zoomImage');
}
```

```css
.active-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#product-gallery-super img {
  width: 61px;
  height: 79px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img class="main-image image-resize product-zoom" src="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=1" data-zoom-image="http://placehold.it/1000x2000?text=1" onerror="comingSoonMain(this)">

  <div id="product-gallery-super">
    <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery active-thumbnail" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=1">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=2">
      <img src="http://yi.yoga/images/cs.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=3">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=4">
    </a>
    <a href="http://simplypx.com/images/Prometheus.mp4" id="video" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=VID">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=5">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=6">
    </a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is difficult to understand. Can you elaborate further? What is the zoom layer?

Comment: @MattWay I have just updated the functionality above (filling in the gaps). If you now click on a few thumbnails, you can see when you hover over hte main image that it zooms in. However, if you click on number 5, the video plays the hover over still is in place. Finally, even if i add a few destroy functions in there, on clicking fast, it still somehow displays the zoom on the video.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out? If the problem was that the video briefly takes up the whole screen before sizing down to a manageable dimension, then try using `<video class="flat-video product-video" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="mainVideo" poster="' + videoImg + '" autoplay autobuffer width="300px" height="auto">` instead of `width=100%`.